# MKMapItem not updating name value

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, xcode9, mkmapitem

I'm launching the iOS maps from my app but is showing "Unknown Locations".

Here is how adding the title to the location:

```
    @IBAction func directionsToLocation(_ sender: Any) {
        let destionationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.annotation.coordinate))
        destionationMapItem.name = "Destionation"
        let startLocation = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.currectLocation))
        startLocation.name = "My current Location"
        MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [destionationMapItem,startLocation], launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeTransit])
    }
```

[image: MKMapItem]
Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong? or why is not taking the value of the name?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Whats the value in `self.annotation.coordinate` and `self.currectLocation`? Is any nil I mean?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFkoN.png For me work just fine, maybe the issue is in other part of your code.

Comment: Seems to be occurring on the simulator only